# Allow access only through iframe

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to block direct access to the pages of my site. Only access from an iframe should be allowed. Example

iframe page -> /path/to/iframe.html

anyotherpage.html-> should be visible only from the iframe in iframe.html

Is there any way to achieve this with htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to check `%{HTTP_REFERER}`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} your\.domain/iframe\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/iframe.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !your\.domain/iframe\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/iframe.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /another_page [R,L]
```

In this rules **iframe.php** = page with iframe tag located.
**iframe.html** = page which using as iframe

So, if you try to request **iframe.html** directly, you will get redirect to another page.

Comment: Thank you Sergio,
the code works. What if I wanted to make it work not only with iframe.html but with any other page except iframe.php? Can it be done without having to repeat the above code for every single html page to target?

Comment: for example, you can replace `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/iframe.html` with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*).html` and this will work for any *.html