# how to protect my content from being framed on other domains

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a website and i provide a free service. 
This service is located on another host which is linked to subdomain. Many people are using my content as iframe and i want to give permission to access only to my domain and subdomain.
Regards.

Comment: see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/33396191/5397119

Comment: i'm looking for a way to restrict access from other domains

Comment: so why can't you checking in .htaccess referrer and host ? if `%{HTTP_HOST}` is not your just return 403 error.

Answer (score 2):

Have your server deliver a `X-Frame-Options` header.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

You can prevent framing (`DENY`), allow framing from just your domain (`SAMEORIGIN`), or allow specific domains (`ALLOW-FROM` - but note that not all browsers support this one).

Comment: i tried but the problem as you said .. it doesen't work with all browsers

Comment: @DZSAT It's supported by all modern browsers. Chrome, Firefox, IE8+, and Safari. The 1% of users on older browsers may get through, but the 99% getting blocked will cause the sites framing your content to give up.

Comment: i used it now on firefox but it didn't work .. may you please give me the full line

Comment: i tried 
Header always append X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM=http:// mydomain .com but it didn't work

Comment: @DZSAT You'll likely want to use `DENY` or `SAMEORIGIN`. Chrome and Safari don't support `ALLOW-FROM`. If it's not working in Firefox, make sure your server is actually sending the header via the web inspector.

Comment: with same origin i can't frame my content into my official domain .. as i said i'm using a new host for my new content but with a subdomain from my officail domain

Comment: Well, then I'd use `ALLOW-FROM` in combination with the JS option mentioned elsewhere in this thread. You said it doesn't work, but I suspect if you check the browser console you'll find out why and be able to fix it. Or just go the simple route and host everything in one place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to detect if your document location is the top location, if not make it the root node.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/break-out-of-iframe/

Comment: what would happen in this case if I turn off javascript?

Comment: Yes there are ways to kill frame killer scripts. To defeat these, you can use the solution recommended here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller#Framekiller_killers. i.e. control visibility on your page as opposed to trying to reload you page at top.